# Return same object as argument

Tags: typescript, tsc, typescript3.0

This is probably an anti-pattern, but I want to return the same object as an argument, in this case like so:

```
const handleConnection = (s: net.Socket): net.Socket => {

  s.pipe(createParser()).on('data', (d: any) => {

    log.info(chalk.green.underline('dygrep server response:'));

    if (d && d.lastMessage) {
      process.stdout.write(prompt);
    }

  });

  return s;

};
```

so what would be ideal is to do something like this:

```
const handleConnection = (s: net.Socket): s => {

  s.pipe(createParser()).on('data', (d: any) => {

    log.info(chalk.green.underline('dygrep server response:'));

    if (d && d.lastMessage) {
      process.stdout.write(prompt);
    }

  });


  return s;

};
```

but yeah that's not quite right - how do I tell TypeScript that I am returning one of the arguments?

Comment: Are you trying to enforce in compile-time the fact that the argument and return value are not only of the same type, but necessarily the same object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I tell TypeScript that I am returning one of the arguments

Generics. The constraint is the return is same as argument e.g.

```
function handleConnection<T extends net.Socket>(arg:T):T{}
```

Here whatever is passed in as arg is what is returned.

Comment: you sure I couldn't return a new net.Socket instance tho? To me, that seems possible given the typings.